# Connection timed out issue in cfexchangeConnection

Tags: windows-7, coldfusion, exchange-server, coldfusion-9

I have windows 7 (32bit), ColdFusion 9 installed on my PC.
My email account is configured in outlook 2007 and it is working fine. But when I try to connect to an exchange server using `cfExchangeConnection` it is not getting connected. It is giving me an error saying:

> ```
> Error connecting to the server mail.domain.com.
> Error message from the server : Connection timed out: connect.
> ```

My cfexchangeConnection  code is:

```
<cfexchangeConnection 
    action="open" 
    username="name@domain.com" 
    protocol="https"  
    password="email_password" 
    server="mail.domain.com" 
    connection="conn1">
```

I have tried `cfmail` and it is working. How can I make `cfExchangeConnection` work in ColdFusion9?